# I want to set a bitmpa on an imageView outside of recyclerView when any item of recyclerview is clicked. Stuck on this problem since past 2 days :(

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, filter, crash

I want to set a bitmap on an imageView outside of recyclerView when any item of recyclerview is clicked

My adapter class looks like this.I have set up a listener at the end of recyclerView too so that it'll listen to the changes

```
public class ThumbnailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ThumbnailAdapter.ThumbnailHolder> {

ArrayList<ThumbnailItem> thumbnailItemList = new ArrayList<>();
Context mContext;
int selectedIndex = 0;
ThumbnailsAdapterListener listener;
Bitmap originalImage;
ImageView imageView;

public static class ThumbnailHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView thumbnail;
    TextView filterName;

    public ThumbnailHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        filterName = view.findViewById(R.id.filter_name);

    }
}


public ThumbnailAdapter(Context mContext, Bitmap originalImage, ImageView imageView, ArrayList<ThumbnailItem> thumbnailItemList, ThumbnailsAdapterListener listener) {
    this.originalImage = originalImage;
    this.imageView = imageView;
    this.thumbnailItemList = thumbnailItemList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.listener = listener;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ThumbnailHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.thumbnail_list_items, parent, false);

    return new ThumbnailHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ThumbnailHolder holder, int position) {

    final ThumbnailItem thumbnailItem = thumbnailItemList.get(position);
    holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(thumbnailItem.image);


    holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Log.i("POSITION", String.valueOf(position));

        listener.onFilterSelected(thumbnailItem.filter);
        selectedIndex = position;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    });


    holder.filterName.setText(thumbnailItem.filterName);


    if (selectedIndex == position) {
        holder.filterName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.dot_blue));
    } else {
        holder.filterName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.grey));
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return thumbnailItemList.size();
}


public interface ThumbnailsAdapterListener {
    public void onFilterSelected(Filter filter);
}
```

And in my MainActivity
I have set up a listener

```
@Override
public void onFilterSelected(Filter filter) {
    //resetControls();

    Bitmap bitmap = filter.processFilter(originalImage);
    Log.i("IWASHERE", filter.getName() + "Here");
    Thread thread = null;

    try {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //finalImage = filteredImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
}
```

I cant understand that whenever i select an image and try to call listener the app crashes.

Comment: Can you post MainActivity ?

Comment: its way too long

Comment: I have just declared a listener as "ThumbnailAdapter.ThumbnailsAdapterListener listener;"    I dont know how to initailise it and use it to change image on imageview